# This is not a group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, orm, decode

So first of all, im using ORM to connect and get data from Oracle DB.

When i call my stored procedure from some database management tool, everything is working fine.

Problem starts when i want to run this from my ORM.
It gives an error:

`ORA-00979: this is not a group by expression`.

Normally it happens when not aggregated or not constant data, does not appear in a group by clausule.

The query is included in stored procedure, so its the same everytime i try to run it, and it has everything needed in a group by clausule.

I even login to the same oracle user. I also made some traces, but nothing strange was there.

The query looks like:

```
 for rec in (
select t1.field1,
      t1.field2,
      t1.field3,
      t1.field4,
      t1.field5,
      decode(parameter,'T',nvl(t1.version, '-'),t1.version),
      sum(nvl(t1.liczba2,0)) as left_to_dispatch
    from table_1 t1 
    group by
      t1.field1,
      t1.field2,
      t1.field3,
      t1.field4,
      t1.field5,
      decode(parameter,'T',nvl(t1.version, '-'),t1.version)) 
  loop 
    null; 
  end_loop;
```

Question is: are there any settings that ORM may set in database (rather in session), that may result in such a error?

Btw. i tried replacing decode to case: i got the same error.

I tried to replace decode to NVL's, i got the same error.

But errors was only from this ORM tool, when i tried to run it from PLSQL Developer, everything worked fine.

Any ideas?

PS. When i change query to a query like this, ORM is working fine:

```
for rec in (
    select t1.field1,
          t1.field2,
          t1.field3,
          t1.field4,
          t1.field5,
          t1.version,
          sum(nvl(t1.liczba2,0)) as left_to_dispatch
        from table_1 t1 
        group by
          t1.field1,
          t1.field2,
          t1.field3,
          t1.field4,
          t1.field5,
          t1.version)
      loop 
        null; 
      end_loop;
```

Comment: What is your ORM tool?  We probably need to know this.  Also, please include the relevant code where you call this query.

Comment: made some edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your two `decode()` statements are not exactly the same.  My recommendation is that you use a subquery and then you won't have to repeat the expression.

I also prefer `case` and `coalesce()` (standard SQL constructs), so:

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3, t1.field4, t1.field5, new_version,
       sum(coalesce(t1.liczba2, 0)) as left_to_dispatch
from (select t1.*
             (case when parameter = 'T' then coalesce(t1.version, '-') else t1.version end) as new_version
      from table_1 t1 
     ) t1
group by t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3, t1.field4, t1.field5, new_version;
```

Comment: hmm, maybe indeed somehow ORM is seeing these decodes in other way than my eyes and other tools. You gave me nice idea, im checking that.

Comment: Well, since there is no doubt about that there is something wrong with the ORM, and i guess its pointless to guess what might be wrong without knowing internal code, im marking your answer as an answer which solves the problem.
Now querys returning same results as they did before, and they are working in both tools.
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

`decode()` is an old Oracle function, which perhaps your ORM has trouble interpreting. Why not use `case` instead? It's standard SQL and so may be easier for the ORM to handle.

```
select t1.field1,
      t1.field2,
      t1.field3,
      t1.field4,
      t1.field5,
      case when parameter = 'T' then coalesce(t1.version, '-') else t1.version end,
      sum(nvl(t1.liczba2,0)) as left_to_dispatch
    from table_1 t1 
    group by
      t1.field1,
      t1.field2,
      t1.field3,
      t1.field4,
      t1.field5,
      case when parameter = 'T' then coalesce(t1.version, '-') else t1.version end
```

Note that I have also replaced `nvl()` with the standard SQL function `coalesce()`. There's nothing wrong with using the old Oracle functions: Oracle still supports them. However, they date from a time when Oracle was innovating SQL faster than the ANSI committee could keep up. Generally speaking, third-party "database agnostic" tools work better with standard SQL than with product specific SQL.

Comment: tried +/- exactly what u did here, and case isnt working aswell. Seems like a bug...
I just tried exactly what you did, and again same situation: error in ORM, no error in PLSQL Developer.

Comment: i also upvoted your answer, since indeed ORM is having problems with interpreting anything above normal field in group by clausule. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score -1):

may be you forgot the comma after 
decode(parameter,'T',nvl(t1.version, '-'),t1.version)

decode(parameter,'T',nvl(t1.version, '-'),t1.version),
 sum(nvl(t1.liczba2,0)) as left_to_dispatch

Comment: please read help center for answer good... https://stackoverflow.com/help